# Displaying SVG objects on either left or right side of page

Tags: javascript, svg

I am dynamically generating some SVG. What I want to do is divide the page in half (no matter what size it is) and be able to insert some objects on the left side of the screen and some objects on the right of the screen. I just can't seem to get it right.  I have actually tried to do it many different ways, the code listed here was my most recent attempt:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%" height="100%">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
   var i = 0;
  function makeBox() {
     i++;
      var newRect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect");

     newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"width", 100); 

     newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"height", 100);
     newRect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 10);
     newRect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", i * 100);
     newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","blue");      


     if(i % 2 === 1) {
     document.getElementById("screenLeft").appendChild(newRect);
      } else {

     document.getElementById("screenRight").appendChild(newRect);

      }
  }


</script>
  <g id="firstGroup">
<text x="20" y="30" onclick="makeBox()" font-size="+13px">Click this text to Draw a Box.</text>
</g>
<svg id="screenLeft" viewBox="50% 100%">
</svg>
<svg id="screenRight" viewBox="50% 100%" x="50%">
</svg>  

</svg>
```

Of course I changed a bunch of code to make this post more concise. What it does is, when user clicks the text, it draws a rectangle in element "screenLeft" or "screenRight" depending on if the increment (i) is even or odd.

The way I have the viewBox setup right now sort of works. If I reduce the chrome window to a smaller size, the gap between the "leftSide" and the "rightSide" does get smaller. However, if I have the window Maximized, the screen area is WAY too big. I have to scroll far to the right to see the "rightSide". It is about twice my screen size.

I have also tried several other methods, involving grouping.

So, I guess my question is, what is the best way to divide the screen in half so I can generate some objects on the left side of the screen and some on the right side of the screen, while allowing the total screen size to differ?

Comment: Side note: it is my opinion that mixing your JS handlers in your SVG markup is a maintenance and development annoyance. I suggest that you not put `onclick` attributes in your markup, but rather programmatically assign the handler(s) to the element(s) as part of your code. `myText.addEventListener('click',makeBox,false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `<svg>` element a [`viewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) with fixed width and an exceptional height. Then specify a [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute with the value of `xMidYMid slice`.

This will ensure that the full width of your SVG viewport will always cover the viewBox, and half of your viewBox will thus cover half the screen.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="-100 -1000 200 2000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    rect { stroke:red }
    text { text-anchor:middle; font-size:8px }
  ]]></style>
  <rect x="-100" y="-1000" width="100" height="2000" fill="lightblue" />
  <rect x="0"    y="-1000" width="100" height="2000" fill="yellow"    />
  <text x="-50" y="0">Left Side</text>
  <text x="+50" y="0">Right Side</text>
</svg>
```

See this live: http://phrogz.net/svg/half-width.svg

The only downside with this (which I can't tell if it matters to you) is that resizing the browser window will resize the elements. Maybe you want elements to always remain the same size on screen no mater how large the browser?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that I wanted the objects to change size depending on the size of the browser. But now that you mention it, maybe that wouldn't be such a good thing for dynamically drawing things. I guess I really don't know enough about this yet to know the implications. So until I get more involved in my little project here, I won't know. Thanks for the help! I am going to try this out now.

Comment: @Phrogz, I used the same code of yours but, with some small changes. For entire code please look this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L5JYz/.

1)used viewBox="0 0 200 2000" instead of viewBox="-100 -1000 200 2000".
2)Changed the left column,right column coordinates accordingly.
Please let me know, if there is any special reason for using such viewBox coordinates(negative ones.). As the same effect can be achieved(think so), like shown in fiddle code.

Comment: @rajkamal No, no reason. I sometimes prefer to have 0,0 in the center of the screen so that the difference between left and right is just ± the same number. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do what I think you wanted, the only thing you need to decide is how you want aspect ratio to effect your display...  I deliberately left the right side's aspect ratio unadjusted so you could see the difference.

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<svg width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>

<svg x="50%" width="50%"  viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="80%" y="10%" width="10%" height="50%" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="70" height="40" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```